# How to check if two-dimensional char array has empty word

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Here there are two two-dimensional character arrays that hold certain words.
I'm trying to make a function that will return a false if the double array contains the word that is empty C-string ('') and true if every word it has contains at least one letter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_WORD_LENGTH = 20;

bool checkEmptyString(const char word[][MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1], int numOfWords);

int main()
{
    const char dict1[][MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1] = {"Hello", "What", ""};
    const char dict2[][MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1] = {"Hello", "Hey" "Man", "Sup"};

    if (checkEmptyString(dict1, 3))
         cout << "Dictionary 1 is empty!" << endl;
    else 
         cout << "Dictionary 1 is not empty!" << endl;

    if (checkEmptyString(dict2, 4))
        cout << "Dictionary 2 is empty!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Dictionary 2 is not empty!" << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool checkEmptyString(const char word[][MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1], int numOfWords)
{
   // Enter code here ... //
}
```

How do I implement the function that way the desired outcome is generated?

Comment: Micronag: instead of `MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1` all over the place, consider something like `const int MAX_WORD_LENGTH_WITH_NULL = MAX_WORD_LENGTH + 1;`

Comment: Macronag: You will get better results if you show your best attempt at implementing `checkEmptyString`. For all we know you could be off by something trivial and the fix is small. Plus people are better motivated if they know you have tried to accomplish your homework before crowdsourcing it.

Comment: [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/)(str) == 0.

Comment: @ffhighwind `strlen` requires iterating the whole string. Testing the first byte for a null char is far less work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<numOfWords; i++) {
    int j=0;
    while(word[i][j]) j++;
    if(!j) return true;
}
return false;
```

I think This will do the job..

Comment: `if (!word[i][0]) return false;` would work in place of the `while` and `if`. All you need is to make sure there is at least one character in each string, so if there is one, no need to count the rest.